# SDXC card refused by Nikon D5500

Tags: nikon, nikon-d5500, sdxc

I recently bought a used Nikon D3100 with several pieces at a bargain, including 2 Huawei Professional 128GB SDXC I V30 U3 C10. I'd very much like to use them in my D5500, but neither of them will be accepted in this camera ("This memory card cannot be used. Card may be damaged. Insert another card"). However, they are working perfectly in the D3100 and in my PC. Both my SDHC cards (including one microSD) are working fine in the D5500.

This error message pops directly when I insert the card, even with the D5500 powered off. It freezes any action, so I can't even access the menu to format it. I tried :

- The lock lever in both positions
- Formatting them in the D3100 then insert them in the D5500
- Formatting them in both NTFS and exFAT on Windows
- Deep formatting them in the official SD software
- Cleaning the contacts on the cards
- No ghost file from dragging a file into an editing software is present (reference to FStopStudio's video)

I'm definitely running out of ideas and getting desperate. This card should be D5500-compatible, especially considering it's from 2015 vs 2010 for the D3100, + 1 step higher in the product range. I can't understand, it's just not logical! If someone has the solution, may their fate be glorious!

Comment: The cards could be borderline. You don't state the brand, are they generic cards?  (if so, highly suspicious anyway). Personally, even if I could finally make them work, I wouldn't trust them with my pictures anyway.

Comment: Thx for pointing out, I edited the post ! Both are Huawei Professional. Not Sandisk, but I guess Huawei may be trustworthy

Comment: @MaxSxB Sandisk never has let me down; I’d replace the cards for sure.

Comment: Cards are cheap. Pictures are (mostly) irreplaceable. I don't want to dismiss anyone's individual budget, but no way I would ever use a memory card that is giving trouble.

Comment: Also, 128GB cards for photo... is one ready to lose over 3000 pictures (in RAW+JPEG...) in case of card problems? Several 32GB cards would be safer.

Comment: What version of firmware is the D5500 running? What is the latest version available from Nikon? There have been cases of specific batches of cards not working in a particular camera model, then the camera maker updating the firmware to work around the issue (sometimes when the cards are the side not conforming to standards).

Comment: @xenoid It's not really for the capacity, it's for the specs, I always empty the card after each session. I got em basically for free so I wanted to make a good use of them, but yes I don't trust them !

Comment: Have you tried formatting with Fat32 using the computer?

Comment: @MichaelC My response didn't show up, don't know why. My D5500 is up to date with 1.02 FW, no mention about card compatibility in changelogs. I tried formatting to FAT32 without success. I will call this unfixable now, as 1 of the cards is starting to have problems (slow, lost formatting in the D3100 between 2 test sessions,...). Better safe than sorry, I'll grab a 32Gb SanDisk for 12€ and it will be fine ! Thx guys for the help